# How do 'hand clap' switches work?

Tags: switches

I'd like to know how a 'hand clap' switch works. You know, the kind where you *clap-clap* and the light turns on, *clap-clap* again and the light turns off.

How is the clapping sound detected? How can it be differentiated from whistling, people talking, a barking dog, ... ? Can it be another kind of sound?

What kind of components would I need to build such a sensor/switch, assuming everything works on DC?

*Note: I am **not** interested in just buying a Velleman kit :-)*

Comment: Actually I can switch my clapper by making two barking sounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most famous example of this was ["The Clapper"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clapper).

See the patents for the details:
[1](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=5493618.PN.&OS=PN/5493618&RS=PN/5493618) and [2](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=5615271.PN.&OS=PN/5615271&RS=PN/5615271)

https://www.instructables.com/id/how-773/step1/Clapper-Circuit-Diagram/

[image]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://www.instructables.com/image/FEQY8PO721EP27V2CO/Clapper-Circuit-Diagram.jpg))</sub>

Here's a recent hackaday post on achieving the same thing:
http://hackaday.com/2011/02/07/diy-clapper/

Comment: On a related note, you can't build this because it's patented for the next 7 years.   :P

Comment: You can't build it and sell it

Comment: You can still build it for "research purposes" but I believe patents would prevent you from selling it or even distributing it for free. (i.e. giving it to a friend.)

Comment: Then how is it distributed as a kit by Vellman?

Comment: @Joby You can still get in trouble even if you aren't selling it @Thomas do you have any sources that say you can still build if for research purposes? @reemrevnivek if I were to guess, they either use a different method or they have a license to use the technology.

Comment: It is very important to note someone with a patent can sue for building with non-commercial intent. You are stealing one sale.

Comment: The idea for patents is that people can learn from your product; that's why you have to publish everything out in the open.

Comment: Thanks. You wouldn't happen to have any other links that aren't a wall of text and feature some schematics? :-)

Comment: This just goes to show that patents are evil and only hinder development. :)

Comment: There are two sides to that @XTL, it also protects those that invent something amazing. I have quite a few problems with the patent system, but there are some things it does correctly.

Comment: @Kortuk: It protects corporations that have lots of lawyers and make mediocre improvements to existing inventions, while they lobby for laws that disenfranchise the little guy that invents something amazing: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/America_Invents_Act#First_to_file_and_grace_period_2

Comment: If you look at this schematic, but don't build it, you could be sued. By not building it, you do not violate the patent. Thereby, you are taking away business from patent lawyers.

Answer (score 6):

What's typical for clapping hands is that it's a sudden short, but strong sound. (The sound of a barking dog may look somewhat similar, but the peaks will be longer.) A possible way to detect it is to trigger an MMV with the input signal if it's higher than a certain threshold, and see if this high level is still present when the MMV times out. If it isn't it was probably clapping hands. You'll have to experiment with threshold level and MMV time.

Not filed for patent :-)

Comment: Isn't this what the schematic in Joby Taffey's answer does?

Comment: it looks different. The microphone output is not used after the 555 (I think that's what it is, as monostable multivibrator). +1

Answer (score -1):

The response of a hand clapper is basically the impulse response of your transfer function. Since the response is the transfer function itself, you can design your transfer function to suit your needs accordingly. The best way is, to sample your sound analyzer input and interface it with a digital signal processor and then go crazy with discrete laplaces and FFTs.

Comment: This really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: why? Can't a hand clap response of a system be used as an impulse response? We've done modelling problems like that in college before, in DSP...

Comment: Yes, hand claps are sometimes used to estimate the impulse response of, say, a reverberant room. But this has absolutely nothing to do with how a clap-operated switch works.

Comment: No, I was talking about differentiating a hand clap signal from  other discrete impulses, using DFT of the signal where the hand clap can be correlated to other hand claps and then a tuned correlation can be achieved, the other sharp signals, like dog barking or engine revving could be differentiated. I have seen one group display a project on that...

Comment: You are *waaay* over-thinking this ...

Comment: Generally, when answering an old question (2010) it's expected that you spend some time in crafting a very good answer that is better than the existing ones. While yours is valid, it doesn't tell a lot to the reader, so doesn't add much value to the post.

Comment: Okay, I'll delete mine if you want...

Comment: It doesn't matter about this answer, but please consider it in the future, because it ends up bringing old questions to the top page in spite of newer questions. Do it only if you think it's really worth it.

Comment: Okay. Apologies for the answer. I'll take care in the future. I had no idea about the old questions popping up again. You have my word, I'll consider...